# How to implement a server side pagination with Material ui and react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, backend

Currently you can paginate towards the backend, with the next and previous option, but I can't do it with the rows per page option, how do I make the two options work? Thank you

**Here is an image of the options**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For paging you need:

1. know the number of records.
2. number of records displayed on page.
3. page number.

Send to server from client: `number of records on page` and `page number`)

Send to client from server: `records` between `from`, `to`

```js
const count = 20; // for example we have 20 records
const size = 7;   // there are 7 records on each page

// number of pages
const countPages = Math.ceil (20/7);

//show records on page 2:
const page = 2; // display 2nd page

const from = (page - 1) * size;
const to = Math.min (from + size- 1, count);

console.log(`we have ${count} records, ${size} per page` )
console.log('number of pages', countPages);
console.log(`on page ${page} records from ${from} to ${to}`);
```